# Fully customising the table of contents in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I am creating a compendium of articles created by my organisation. Each page of the compendium contains the synopsis of one article. Each article has a reference number and an author on separate lines, like this:

Author: Jones, Benjamin
Article ID:   1044562

I would like the contents table to pick up both of these, like this:

Jones, Benjamin  1044562............................p3

How can I get two separate bits of text picked up in the one line? The closest I'm getting (by using the same level Heading) is:

Jones, Benjamin............................p3
1044562....................................p3

which is too untidy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use TC fields, and combine them with STYLEREF fields.  Then add the \f switch to your TOC field to pick up the TC fields in your table of contents.

Create 2 new character styles (eg chAuthor and chID).  Then apply the relevant style to each author name and ID (ie just the text you want to show in the TOC).

After the ID, you can insert your TC field which includes the 2 STYLEREF fields - one to pick up author name and one to pick up ID number (once you've created one TC field, just copy and paste it and then update all fields).

If you put the TC field on the same line after the ID number, make sure that you don't have the chID style applied to your TC field.  Note also that you enclose the STYLEREF fields in quotation marks.

[image]